# Portfolio folder is not visible to upload social share icons

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I want to update default social share icons in salesforce marketing cloud. I got to know there exist a folder name "Portfolio" where these icons can be updated but I'm not able to locate this folder in content builder, i.e. the folder doesn't exist.

How can I access this folder?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can access Portfolio folder:

Go to Email Studio--> Click on 'Content'--> Click on 'Use Classic Content' (on the top left corner).
Here in the left panel, you should be able to see Portfolio folder.

But just FYI, they are ending support to Classic Content soon and for uploading any such content, you can do that Using Content Builder as well.

Please find the link here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_upload_files.htm&type=5

Comment: Additionally it's worth noting out that Classic Content isn't even enabled for new Marketing Cloud instances since Q1 2018. Here's a list of features that are either replaced or removed: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_content_builder_and_email_creation_consideration_list.htm&type=5